# SharePoint - How to set default value in DropDownMenu which takes data in SPList?

Tags: dropdown, server

**I Have list "Department" and takes the data from it. I want the first value in DropDownMenu to be "Not a dept"...**

---

[image]

---

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://sf-spsdev04/sites/sitecolection/"))
            {
                using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                {
                    SPList list = web.Lists["Departments"];
                    dropDep.DataSource = list.Items;
                    dropDep.DataValueField = "Title";
                    dropDep.DataTextField = "Title";
                    dropDep.DataBind();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add below line of code under `dropDep.DataBind();`

```
ListItem newItem = new ListItem("Not a dept", "0");
dropDep.Items.Insert(0, newItem);
```

Comment: Please help me for this question ...  ----> [link](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/174027/sharepoint-caml-query-where-check-textbox-for-existing-user-name)